# qTip2 always closes whenever leaving the element

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, qtip2

I have a table heaving divs inside all cells. These divs have a `qTip2` to show extra information. Since the table can be pretty big I create the `qTip2` elements when I hover over the div. The `qTip2` then is shown when the user clicks on the item.

```
$('#queryResult div[data-distribution]').each(function() {
    var element = $(this);
    var distribution = element.data('distribution');

    element.hover(function() {
        element.qtip({
            content: {
                text: function() {
                    return '<div class="distributionTitle">Distribution:</div><div class="distributrionBody">' + distribution + '</div>';
                },
               title: 'Information',
               button: true
            },
            show: 'click',
            position: {
                my: 'top center',
                at: 'bottom center'
            },
            hide: {
                fixed: true,
                delay: 5000,
                event: false
            }                       
        });
    });
});
```

The `qTip2` appears as intended when I click on any of the elements. But it disappears as soon as I leave the `div` I created the `qTip2` on. I tried several versions of `hide`, non of them worked.

Browser: IE9

Answer (score 0):

@Tscheuge This should do it.

```
hide: {
  fixed: true,
  event: false,
  leave: false  // emphasis here
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mijopabe/2njmD/)